# How to reference a JSON example in set payload

Tags: json, mule, anypoint-studio, payload

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1 and have a JSON example in main/src/api called response-flow1.json.  I want to set my payload to response-flow1.json if certain rules are met.  How can I reference response-flow1.json in a Set Payload?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To save the trouble of loading a file (Only if it's a small JSON), you can set your JSON payload in a variable in a properties file. Then call it like this:

```
<set-payload value="#[${samplejson}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

If this is not the answer you were looking for, please provide more information and I'll be glad to help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following: -
 `<set-payload value="#[Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('response-flow1.json')]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>`
Best practice will be keeping the `response-flow1.json` under resource folder

Answer (score 0):

We have the option to use the dataweave:

```
<set-payload value="#[dw('readUrl(&quot;classpath://examples/filename.json&quot;,&quot;application/json&quot;)')]" doc:name="Set Mock Payload"/>
```